# Difference between setCallBack and getCallBack function?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Please tell the difference between `setCallBack` and `getCallBack` function? Also, If possible can someone please tell me why what is .this function and what does this code is actually doing. (Its related to Instant Notification App https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/workshop-platform-events/platform-event-subscribe)

```
const callback = function (message) {
      console.log('Event Received : ' + JSON.stringify(message));
      helper.onReceiveNotification(component, message);
    };

    // Subscribe to the channel and save the returned subscription object.

    empApi.subscribe(channel, replayId, $A.getCallback(callback)).then($A.getCallback(function (newSubscription) {
      console.log('Subscribed to channel ' + channel);
      component.set('v.subscription', newSubscription);
    }));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`action.setCallback()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm#!) is used to provide a callback function when making a call to a server-side Apex controller:

```
    var action = component.get("c.someMethod");
    action.setParams({ param: cmp.get("v.aParameter") });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        // Do things.
    }
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
```

[`$A.getCallback()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_mod_ext_js.htm) is used when passing a callback function to a function outside the Lightning framework that might interact with a component outside the normal rendering lifecycle, such as `setTimeout()`:

```
window.setTimeout(
    $A.getCallback(function() {
        cmp.set("v.visible", true);
    }), 5000
);
```

You do not need to use `$A.getCallback()` when interacting with Apex server controller methods.

The code that you posted is using the `<lightning:empApi>` component to subscribe to a Platform Event. The subscription is handled by a JavaScript library that speaks the CometD protocol and callbacks are performed asynchronously at any time. Hence the use case falls into the realm of `$A.getCallback()` as described above.

Comment: Thanks David for explanation. So the getCallBack method will execute when we are calling a method that is not part of aura framework. If possible can tell please tell me how below code is working:

Comment: If you have specific code, please edit it into your question.

Comment: Hi David, Please let me know if you can help here.